# Getting Email referrer address

Tags: php

I have a requirement to know the referrer URL and i am using `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` it works fine for the websites which is referring to my site but it is not showing any url when the link has been clicked from any email inbox.

Comment: You would also have an empty `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` if I copy the link from website, open up new window/tab, paste the URL into address bar and hit ENTER...

Comment: When a user comes from an email he's kind of not being refered, so I assume an empty result to be accurate. Also, as already stated in an answer below, HTTP_REFERER cannot really be trusted. Why not add a URL parameter to the email link and use that to track that the click came from an email?

Comment: What would you expect the URL to be when it comes from an email? An email isn't a web page.

Comment: If you want this you need to craft special links inside the email that can tell you where it came from. It's something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't do this with HTTP_REFERER. Email clients, or anyone else for matter, are not obliged to provide this header with a request.

From [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php):

> The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.

As noted in the comments, you would have to embed tracking information in the link that the user clicks if it is within your control to do so.

Comment: Thank you. no i can't make any change in url. i will try to change the architecture of the process & append some code to identify it.